# AngularJS Flexslider Buttons and Margin Issue

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-scope, flexslider

I am trying to implement a simple `angular-flexslider` app within my project:

https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider

I have been successful in sliding the images, but i cannot get the next/previous buttons to show, also, there seems to be a left margin which shows the previous image.

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>Angular FlexSlider Example - Basic Slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/master/flexslider.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    .flexslider-container {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 1px auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body ng-controller="BasicSliderCtrl">

  <flex-slider slide="s in slides"  animation="slide"  >
    <li>
      <img ng-src="{{s}}">
    </li>
  </flex-slider>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/master/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider/master/angular-flexslider.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('BasicSlider', ['angular-flexslider'])
      .controller('BasicSliderCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.slides = [
          'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg',
          'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg',
          'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg',
          'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg'
        ];
      });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2529sAA4i6qcCzbZgCA2

Here's what i am trying to achieve: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still have this issue but I ran into both of these problems myself.  The fixes that worked for me are below.

**Issue 1 - next/previous buttons not showing**

The next and previous buttons are shown using css.  Ensure that flexslider.css is included in your page.

Also, if you open up flexslider.css you will see under an "Icon fonts" comment (its near the top) some source urls.  Ensure that these source urls match the location of the flexslider font files in your project.

**Issue 2 - Left Margin showing previous image**

Add the following code to a css file included on your page

```
.carousel li {margin-right:0;}
```